# How to find minimum number of nodes directly connecting all other nodes in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

> let graph $G = {V,E}$.
>   I want to find a minimum subset $A$ of $V$ such that all nodes in $A$ directly connect
>   to all nodes in $(V - A)$

PS:- this is different than minimum vertex cover problem.

Comment: So, like a [minimum vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover)? If so, and you're looking for an efficient way to do it, you're kind of out of luck.

Comment: no, minimum vertex cover says that all edges has atleast one end point in subset A, unlike my question.

Comment: Ah yeah, I see the distinction now.

Comment: so any thoughts?

Comment: Not immediately. The tricky part (at least at a glance) would be proving minimality.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you really want the smallest set of nodes $A$ such that every node $a\in A$ and every node $b\in V-A$ have an edge between them, this is always vacuously satisfied by $A=\varnothing$. Are you sure you don't want the smallest set $A$ such that every node in $V-A$ is connected to at least one node in $A$?

Comment: I think you are asking the following question: which is the most uneven complete bipartite graph $K_{k,n-k}$ which is a subgraph of $(V,E)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at $G^c$, the complement of $G$.
Suppose $G^c$ is disconnected.  Then any connected component $C$ of $G^c$ is such that, in $G$, every vertex of $C$ connects to all vertices of $V - C$.  The $A$ you're looking for is the smallest connected component of $G^c$.
If $G^c$ is connected, then $A$ does not exist.  That is because for any choice of $A$, there will be an edge going from $A$ to $V - A$ in $G^c$ (and this edge won't be in $G$, making every $A$ a bad choice).